# How to populate text inputs with data values from Chosen multiselect?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen jQuery multiselect-plugin to create selects from database.
My table looks like this:

```
|   id   |   text1   |   text2    |
-----------------------------------
|   rs1  |  rs1text  |  rs1text2  |
|   rs2  |  rs2text  |  rs2text2  |
|   rs3  |  rs3text  |  rs3text2  |
```

How to populate text input fields #textinput1 and #textinput2 with data-values from text1 and text2? All i'm able to get to inputs are values of id. When I select 2 options (rs1 and rs3), this is what I get in console:

```
[rs1: {…}, rs3: {…}]
rs1: {text2: 'rs1text2', text1: 'rs1text ', id: 'rs1'}
rs3: {text2: 'rs3text2', text1: 'rs3text ', id: 'rs3'}
```

Nothing comes to inputs #textinput1 and #textinput2. I expect the inputs to get data values as texts like this: #textinput1 - rs1text, rs3text or rs1text (line break) rs3text.

This is my code so far:

```
jQuery(".chosen").chosen({ 
        placeholder_text : "Select", 
        search_contains: true,
    });

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#chosen_select").on('change', function() {
        var selected=[];
        jQuery("#chosen_select :selected").each(function() {
            selected[jQuery(this).val()]=jQuery(this).data();
            });
        jQuery("#textinput1").val(selected["text1"]).prop('readonly', true);
        jQuery("#textinput2").val(selected["text2"]).prop('readonly', true);
        console.log(selected);
    })
})
```

Comment: Given the selected values you show in your example, what do you expect to see in the input boxes?  The first problem i think is that you're trying to use `selected['text1']` but selected is an object with keys `H201` and `H220` so you'd first need to dig into that hash a little deeper and it's not clear (from your example) what you actually expect to see in the text box.  Can you add your expected outcome to the description?

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong keys in my example. Id's (rs1, rs3) are the keys. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.

There are 2 noteworthy modifications here (compared with your code).

1. `selected` is initialized as an object (`{}`) not an array.
2. when pulling the text1 and text2 values, we dig down into the selected object using the key that was selected.

```
  jQuery("#chosen_select").on("change", function () {
    var selected = {};
    jQuery("#chosen_select :selected").each(function () {
      selected[jQuery(this).val()] = jQuery(this).data();
    });
    const selectedText1Values = [];
    const selectedText2Values = [];
    for (key in selected) {
      const data = selected[key];
      selectedText1Values.push(data.text1);
      selectedText2Values.push(data.text2);
    }
    
    jQuery("#textinput1").val(selectedText1Values.join(", ")).prop("readonly", true);
    jQuery("#textinput2").val(selectedText2Values.join(", ")).prop("readonly", true);
    console.log(selected);
  });
```

I don't know exactly what your HTML looks like but I made a guess and put this into play in this codepen. https://codepen.io/bunnymatic/pen/bGLjoBw

Hopefully this helps out.